# Are there moderation options to mark other's answers as the correct answer?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions, community-user

I recently see a lot of questions that are given attention by the Community-user, but they actually have been answered by the OP. They are just not marked as such.

One example of such question is this one: [CKeditor adding an extra <br/> tag when a <br/> tag is encountered](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/155593/ckeditor-adding-an-extra-br-tag-when-a-br-tag-is-encountered) But I have seen quite some more the past days.

Is there a way for moderators for mark these questions on behalf of these users so the Community-user will not rotate them anymore? And if so, are moderators willing to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there's no way for anyone except the OP to accept an answer (well, devs can, but I don't imagine they would).

Accepting an answer is a way for the OP *themselves* to say "this answer in particular helped me", so conceptually it wouldn't make a huge amount of sense for others to be able to make that judgement.

Mods aren't supposed to make decisions based on the technical accuracy of answers either, so even if the system physically allowed it, you probably wouldn't see it happen.

Comment: I agree there would be a lot of cases where such a decision would be very subjective, however the questions I refer to (and the linked one) are answered questions where the OP literally said "I solved it doing this and that". Allowing someone to mark them would remove them from the unanswered questions list and from circulation. I'd say it would be a nice feature.

Comment: From that point of view it would make sense, definitely. I'm not sure if the potential for abuse/uncaught mistakes outweighs it though. It's something that would have to be implemented network-wide I think, major changes like that tend not to happen for individual sites. It's been brought up on meta.se and meta.so probably dozens of times before and declined every time so I don't hold a lot of hope for it :)

Comment: Then I'll leave it to rest :) Thanks for clearing it up.